# How to create a matrix of semaphores

Tags: c, matrix, struct, system, semaphore

I've a problem with this code, I've to create a matrix of semaphores using the struct "tavole" but when i compile there is an error:

error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘int’ using type ‘sem_t {aka union   }’
    tavole matrici = {chessboard[SO_ALTEZZA][SO_BASE], sem_matrix[SO_ALTEZZA][SO_BASE], posFree};

Can you explain me why?

```
   typedef struct {
        int scacchiera[SO_ALTEZZA][SO_BASE];
        sem_t semafori[SO_ALTEZZA][SO_BASE];
        int posLibere;
   }tavole;

 int main(void){
    void inizializza_matrice(int matrice[SO_ALTEZZA][SO_BASE],    
                             int   n);
    void inizializza_sem_matrix(
                            sem_t matrice[SO_ALTEZZA][SO_BASE], 
                            int n);
    int chessboard[SO_ALTEZZA][SO_BASE], posFree = 0, value = 0;
    sem_t sem_matrix[SO_ALTEZZA][SO_BASE];
    tavole matrici = 
                {chessboard[SO_ALTEZZA][SO_BASE], 
                 sem_matrix[SO_ALTEZZA][SO_BASE],
                 posFree}; 

    inizializza_matrice(matrici.scacchiera, 0);
    inizializza_sem_matrix(matrici.sem_matrix, 0);

    for(int i = 0; i < SO_ALTEZZA; i++){
         printf("\n");
         for(int j = 0; j < SO_BASE; j++){
         sem_getvalue(&matrici.semafori[i][j], &value);
         printf("%d ", value);
         }
    }


     return 0;
     }

     void inizializza_matrice
          (int matrice[SO_ALTEZZA][SO_BASE], int n){
             for(int i = 0; i < SO_ALTEZZA; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < SO_BASE; j++){
                   matrice[i][j] = n;
                }
             }
          }

          void inizializza_sem_matrix
               (sem_t matrix[SO_ALTEZZA][SO_BASE], int n){
                   for(int i = 0; i < SO_ALTEZZA; i++){
                        for(int j = 0; j < SO_BASE; j++){
                            sem_init(&matrix[i][j], 0, n);
                        }
                    }
          }
```

Comment: You can't initialise array in that way, you have to initialise the arrays  at the moment of declaration of the structure or trough a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace this:

```
int chessboard[SO_ALTEZZA][SO_BASE], posFree = 0, value = 0;
sem_t sem_matrix[SO_ALTEZZA][SO_BASE];
tavole matrici = 
                {chessboard[SO_ALTEZZA][SO_BASE], 
                 sem_matrix[SO_ALTEZZA][SO_BASE],
                 posFree};
```

With this:

```
int value = 0;
tavole matrici;
```

You don't need to declarate the struct members before creating the struct.

There is also another problem in the code. You should replace this:

```
inizializza_sem_matrix(matrici.sem_matrix, 0);
```

With this:

```
inizializza_sem_matrix(matrici.semafori, 0);
```

Because the name of the struct member is `semafori`, not `sem_matrix`.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your struct needs arrays, but you pass single elements

Replace:

```
tavole matrici = 
        {chessboard[SO_ALTEZZA][SO_BASE], 
         sem_matrix[SO_ALTEZZA][SO_BASE],
         posFree};
```

with

```
tavole matrici = 
        {chessboard, 
         sem_matrix,
         posFree};
```